# docker-stack.yml invalid volume type bind

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

This is my docker-stack.yml file

```
    version: "3"

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        deploy:
          replicas: 1
          update_config:
            parallelism: 1
          restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <Censored>
          MYSQL_USER: <Censored>
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: <Censored>
        volumes:
          - ./db/data:/var/lib/mysql
          - ./db/logs:/var/log/mysql
          - ./db/config:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      php:
        image: wiput1999/php
        volumes:
          - ./web:/web
      nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
        volumes:
          - ./code:/code:ro
          - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
          - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
          - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
```

When I run this following stack I got mysql and nginx with this error
"invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist"

I have no idea what wrong with my code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`bind` is a type of mount that is used to mount a directory (or a file) on the host *into* the container. All of your volumes are set up like that. So one of your source directories (or files) do not exists **on the host**. Check each of these:

- ./db/data
- ./db/logs
- ./db/config
- ./web
- ./code
- ./site.conf
- /etc/letsencrypt
- ./nginx/log

You could execute `ls -ld ./db/data ./db/logs ./db/config ./web ./code ./site.conf /etc/letsencrypt ./nginx/log >/dev/null` and look at the error message to find out which one.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. On docker-compose v2, it used to create those folder on the host if it was missing. I didn't know the behavior changed for swarm.

Answer (score 6):

Please consider to use docker configs and docker secrets in place of volumes.

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  nginx:
    configs:
      - source: nginx_vhost
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    secrets:
      - ssl_private_key
...

configs:
  nginx_vhost:
    file: ./site.conf

secrets:
  ssl_private_key:
    file: /etc/letsencrypt/private.key
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/ and https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#configs